# how to split the value with characters and numbers in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

i have values like `ABC1234`, `AB12`, `CDFHY1234` etc. in the excel am reading from in SSIS and i would need to split them separating letters and numbers.
as you can see we cant predict the number letters those can be in the value.

Please help me to figure out a way to split them separately in SSIS.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Specifically, are you looking for an SSIS Expression that will do this? Or, will something in T-SQL do?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to add a Script Component in your `DataFlowTask` and add 2 output Columns in it. and mark your Column as an Input Column.

Second, You Have to use a script to split this String Value.

Inside your script Declare these Functions

```
Private Shared Function GetNum(ByVal value As String) As Integer
    Dim mytext As String = String.Empty
    Dim myChars() As Char = Value.ToCharArray()
    For Each ch As Char In myChars
         If Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
              myText &= ch
         End If
    Next
    Return Cint(myText)
End Function


Private Shared Function GetText(ByVal value As String) As String
    Dim mytext As String = String.Empty
    Dim myChars() As Char = Value.ToCharArray()
    For Each ch As Char In myChars
         If Char.IsLetter(ch) Then
              myText &= ch
         End If
    Next
    Return myText
End Function
```

Consider that your input Column is `inCol` and your Output Columns are `outNum` and `outText`

```
If Row.inCol_IsNull = False Then
    Row.outText = GetText(Row.inCol)
    Row.outNum = GetNum(Row.inCol)
Else
    Row.outText_IsNull = True
    Row.outNum_IsNull = True
End If
```